# How to count ip's used for logins from a logfile within a bash script?

Tags: arrays, bash, ip, logfile

I look for a way to count the login attempts from each ip by parsing a log file (var/log/auth). I already found a way to do this but it is ugly and needs a lot of time because of the fu*** file operations.

Couldnt this be done with variables only? What I want is a listing like ip=count...

Many thanks

This is what I dont want :)

```
for ip in $(cat /var/log/auth.log | grep sshd | grep Failed | grep -v invalid | awk '{ print $11; }'); do
        if [ -e "log/$ip" ]; then
                file="log/$ip"
                counter=$(cat "$file")
                counter=$[$counter +1]
                echo $counter > log/$ip
        else 
                echo 1 >> log/$ip
        fi
done
```

A sample from the logfile is

```
Jul 30 21:07:30 Server sshd[20895]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.20 port 41448 ssh2
Jul 30 21:07:31 Server sshd[20897]: Failed password for root from 61.177.172.44 port 28603 ssh2
```

What I want is something like 
58.242.83.20=1932
61.177.172.44=3

Comment: what about using `wc -l`? ;-) `NB_IPS = $(cat /var/log/auth.log | grep sshd | grep Failed | grep -v invalid | awk '{ print $11; } | wc -l)`

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The problem on the wc -l statement is that there are different ips and i want to extract all ips then count the login attempts

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea using `awk` with `sort` and `uniq`:

```
awk '$5 ~ "sshd" && $6 = "Failed" && $9 != "invalid" { print $11 }' auth.log | sort | uniq -c
```

Or just `awk`:

```
awk '$5 ~ "sshd" && $6 = "Failed" && $9 != "invalid" { ips[$11]++ } END { for (ip in ips) print ip"="ips[ip]}' auth.log
```

Comment: I suggest to add `&& $9 != "invalid"` to exclude lines with `invalid` as requested my Johannes Brunner.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks! I missed that. I have updated the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po 'sshd.*Failed password for [^i]* \K[0-9.]{7,14}' file | sort | uniq -c
```

works perfect for me... 
thanks to Cyrus

Comment: I removed my comment to your question because it won't work if username starts with `i`. I suggest to use archimiro's answer with my comment to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

try one more approach with awk, where it will provide you output in same order in which IPs have come into your Input_file.

```
awk '!/invalid/ && /Server sshd.*Failed password/{
        match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/);
        val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
        if(!a[val]){
          b[++i]=val
        };
        a[val]++
        }
    END{
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
           print b[j],a[b[j]]
        }
  }'   Input_file
```